# neither TexShop nor TexWorks compile

Tags: installing, texlive, texshop, texworks, amsart

I just bought a new macbook pro and transferred everything from my previous laptop here. Neither TexShop nor TexWorks can even compile the basic tex templates (such as article or amsart, the error is: **File `article.cls' not found. OR: File`amsart.cls' not found**.).

I reinstalled TexLive and I checked specifically and it includes these cls files in texlive.tlpdb. But for some reason TexShop cannot find them. I have set this path:
`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/:$PATH`
but still nothing.

I have also reinstalled TexShop (both versions) but had no success.

Comment: Did you use the MacTeX installation?

Comment: Is there something like a command line on a Mac? If, what's the result of `kpsewhich article.cls` ?

Comment: I tried using the MacTex installation but it just tells me Installation Failed and aborts.

Comment: Well, if the MacTeX installation failed, no wonder things aren't working as expected.

Comment: very true indeed. now what?

Comment: Keks Dose, there is a command line but I don't have kpsewhich installed. Is this similar to the which command?

Comment: I guess I'll try to instead troubleshoot the MacTex installation.

Comment: kpsewhich is a part of texlive and tells you the location of a file

Comment: Just to make sure: was your previous laptop a Mac, too?

Comment: yes, macbook pro.

Comment: Problem solved. My MacTex package was corrupted during download. I checked it using the instructions here http://www.tug.org/mactex/2013/faq/index.html#qm01

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a corrupt download.